# Continuous Azure WebJob using System.Threading.Timer

Tags: multithreading, azure, timer, job-scheduling, azure-webjobs

I am trying to write a continuous Azure WebJob that runs every 60 seconds but without using the Azure Scheduler Service and using System.Threading.Timer instead. Before the general release I was able to do it by doing the following code but after resuming work on this project and updating all NuGet packages to latest versions, the job no longer runs at the given interval. No errors are thrown if I comment the timer code and manually call the "DoWork()" method so that's not the problem.

```
..
const int INTERVAL_SECONDS = 60;
..

static void Main()
{
    JobHost host = new JobHost();
    host.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("StartJob"));
    host.RunAndBlock();
}

[NoAutomaticTrigger]
public static void StartJob()
{
    int dueTime = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(INTERVAL_SECONDS).TotalMilliseconds;
    Timer timer = new Timer(o => DoWork(), null, dueTime, -1);
}

public static void DoWork()
{
    // Do something every XX seconds
}
```

Are there any new changes for WebJobs that I am not aware of? Are they now forcing everyone to use Azure Scheduler to perform such tasks or am I missing something?

Comment: "They" have no ability to disable timers. As long as you can run any code at all you can use timers. The problem is something else.

Answer (score 1):

Well after some digging around I came across the fact that `System.Threading.Timer` isn't thread safe (the irony) and my assumption is after the introduction of Async support in WebJobs something changed in the SDK to break the above code between the preview version I was using and GA release of the WebJobs SDK.

Changing the above to use a `System.Timers.Timer` instead of `System.Threading.Timer` works as expected:

```
var dueTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(INTERVAL_SECONDS).TotalMilliseconds;
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(dueTime);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => { DoWork(); };
timer.Start();
```